# Reporting Services - Header Columns not showing?

Tags: reporting-services, pagination, header

I'm using Reporting Services 2008 and Report Builder 2.0. I've used a tablix to display my data in a simple way - essentially each row in the database receives a row in the tablix - nothing fancy. I have a header row with a name for each column. I also have a super-header which groups together a few of the columns into logical groups (e.g. basics, address related, etc.). Now when I generate the report everything looks beautiful - but if I page to the next page it doesn't show the headers. I've tried setting the Repeat Header Rows on Each Page but it doesn't seem to help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved selected advanced next to row groups and column groups then it would show me the additional header rows. I could then select one of these header rows and change the property RepeatOnNewPage to True.

Answer (score 2):

1. In the Tablix properties check the boxes for: Repeat header rows on each page and Keep header visible while scrolling.
2. Make sure that the column headers check boxes are NOT checked.
3. In the Group pane on the left (Row Groups), the first line is static. Set the following    for this first static only
4. set its: "ReapetOnNewPage" property to TRUE
   set its: "FixedData" property to TRUE
   set its: "KeepWithGroup" property to AFTER

It will work surely!

Source : Answer by ambk on this [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6d6ad0d2-439e-458a-a64a-e427ca628a9e/reporting-services-2008-repeating-headers-when-headers-are-in-a-rectangle-in-header-cell)

Answer (score 0):

In your RDLC file, make sure that you have a Header node specified.  It is possible that you are referring to your "Table" headers, which is not the same as the Report RDLC Header.  The Report Header is the one that will repeat using the RepeatHeader property.